# How do I enable an SSH server port in Raspian? (Raspberry Pi debian)

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm going to set up a Raspberry Pi B+ without keyboard, mouse and screen. I'm only going to use PuTTy (MS-windows, ssh client) and an ethernet cable between my Raspberry Pi and my router.

Raspberry Pi's hard drive is a SD-card and on the SD-card there is a file named "cmdline". I open the file "cmdline" and added in "ip=192.168.1.2" to sett the IP address on the Raspberry Pi.

Tutorial:
https://youtu.be/Ioih6MHNNqc?t=1m1s

Then I wrote this command:

```
nmap -F 192.168.1.1-100
```

It scans all the IP adresses from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.100

Then I found 192.168.1.2

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.2
Host is up (0.0084s latency).
All 100 scanned ports on 192.168.1.2 are closed
```

But the ports are closed. How can I open ports? Can I do that in the file "cmdline"?

Comment: Where is this file `cmdline`?

Comment: It's on the boot folder at the SD-card of the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve here? Opening a port is a means, not an end.

Comment: If you see the video I attached, you can see that I trying to get connection to my Raspberry Pi without using any screen, mouse or keyboard. Only PuTTy. I can sett the adress on my Raspberry Pi, but still, I cannot connect it.

Comment: You may be able to tell you router, to always give the same IP address to the PI (static IP). Else you can install avahi on the PI, and then use avahi/bonjor/zeroconf or what ever it is called on a MS-windows PC. to discover the IP address. Also consider setting up public/private key and disabling password login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer now!

Just add a empty file named "ssh" with no extenstion such as .txt or .c. Only "ssh" in the boot folder and rootfs folder of the SD card for the Raspberry Pi.

Then go to your router and find what IP the raspberry pi is set at.

[image]

Comment: This is actually funny, https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/ the ssh server is disabled by default.

Comment: Well done ☺. Happy Gnu/Linuxing. You now have the same OS, as all 500 of the top 500 super computers (and about 60% of the web, but not this site), and …

Answer (score 3):

In bash type `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

This will install the ssh server, it will listen on port 22, port 22 will become open. For what you have said you are trying to do, you do not need any other ports open.

To do this, you can not remote login, because ssh is the remote login tool. Therefore, do one of these.

- When you setup noobs, tell it to install ssh-server (that would be another question). According to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/59429/17370 you need to add a file named `ssh` to the boot directory, by removing SD card, and using another machine (do read this other question).
- Connect SD card to another Unix box, and use it to install ssh-server (that would be another question).
- Connect a monitor and keyboard to the pi (temporarily), and type the command.

---

Also nmap only scanned 100 ports, there are many more than that 
( 2¹⁶ = 65536 ). So tell nmap to scan them all (it will be slower).

Comment: But that need to be already installed onto raspberry pi. I still cannot contact my Raspberry Pi via PuTTy.

Comment: No you install it, because it is not installed. If ssh-sever is not installed then you can not putty to it. I will add some choices.

Comment: Ok! I sett the IP adress on my rasp to 192.168.1.5 and check if my rasp is avaiable "nmap -F 192.168.1.1-100" and the results was: Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.5
Host is up (0.011s latency).
All 100 scanned ports on 192.168.1.5 are closed

Comment: I try to connect my rasp now via Putty. Cannot connect it via 192.168.1.5

Comment: Why did you change its address? And You need ssh-server running on the Pi.

Comment: Okej. But why could the user in the video connect his rasp via Putty without ssh-server?

Comment: This may help with enabling ssh-server (sshd) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/59429/17370

Answer (score 2):

You "open" a port simply by having a program listening for incoming connections *on* that port:

```
$ nc -l 12345
```

Poof!  Port 12345 is now open and listening for incoming connections because `nc` is waiting for one.

A port being "closed" doesn't mean it's locked down; it simply means that there's nothing there listening for an incoming connection request.

If your question is more specifically about connecting *via secure shell* and not just generically establishing a connection to an arbitrary port, you need to install and start a secure shell server:

```
# apt install openssh-server
# service sshd start
```

Comment: nc: Permission denied
When I try it. Super user won't work neither.

Comment: You should only get `Permission denied` if trying to open a port below 1000 as a non-superuser.

Comment: Did not work for my Raspberry Pi. I still got Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.2
Host is up (0.0099s latency).
All 100 scanned ports on 192.168.1.2 are closed

Comment: Added the text "ip=192.168.1.2 nc -l 8080" in the cmdline file.

Comment: I tried now "ip=192.168.1.2 8080". Didn't work.

Comment: I tried now "ip=192.168.1.2:8080". Didn't work neither.

Comment: No. The command in this answer, should be typed into the shell (the command line) (not a file called cmdline). It will listen on port 12345, and redirect stdin and stdout to/from the connection.

Comment: What did you change the number to, when you get permission denied?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I change number to 80 when I got premission denied.

Comment: I did try that on my local computer.

Comment: That would happen, only root can connect < 1000. `nc` may not be what you want, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I trying to connect my Raspberry Pi at the begninning of the installation, without mouse, keyboard and screen. Only by using Putty.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson OK, again - select a port that is greater than 1000, something like `nc -l 1234` and with `nmap`  specify a particular port `nmap -p 1234 192.168.1.1`  or a range `nmap -p 1-2000 192.168.1.1`. I may be mistaken but `nmap` may be defaulting to ports below 1000, and you need to specify range above that

Comment: If OP is trying to connect using PuTTY, an SSH client, _that should be specified in the question_.  The answer then is to install and start an SSH server.

Comment: While this answer will allow one to open a port. I think it is confusing the OP. We are opening a port for no reason (it is too abstract).

Comment: That's because the _question_ was about opening a port, not about connecting via Secure Shell.

Comment: @DopeGhoti It is specified in the 1st paragraph.

Comment: I fixed the title to match the question (and comments).

Comment: I have similarly addressed the tags, and my answer to explicitly answer the Y problem in this XY problem (to wit: how to install and start an SSH server).

Comment: When I don't set any IP adress on my Rasp, the rasp set the default IP to 192.168.1.34. I can see that on my router. But still, cannot connect it for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

first you need to install openssh-server on the pi.

1- plug your keyboard and your screen into it

2- boot it and open a terminal

3- download and install openssh-server deb package

```
    $ apt-get install openssh-server
```

4- enable and start sshd

```
    $ systemctl enable sshd
    $ systemctl start sshd
```

now you ll be able to ssh into the pi

Answer (score 1):

I found that access to port 22 was opened when I went to  Preferences / Raspberry Pi Configuration, chose Interfaces tab and marked SSH as "enabled".